# Allow entities owned by one user to be referenced by other users' entities

Tags: design, domain-model, modeling, entity

I am working on an Asp.NET MVC web application.

I have the following (simplified) entities:

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public EventArea EventArea { get; set; }
}

public class EventArea
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public CoOrdinate CoOrdinate { get; set; }
}

public class CoOrdinate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Latitude { get; set; }
    public int Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Users can register and create their own Course entities. Each Course has a geographical location, represented by an EventArea which can also be created by a user.

As an EventArea represents a geographical location it should be available for use by other users who want to create a course in the same location.

However making EventArea entities available to users other than the creator raises the following questions:

1. What happens if the EventArea is modified or deleted by the creating user?
2. Who should be able to view/edit/modify an EventArea entity?

Any alternative suggestions for how to approach a scenario where an entity created by one user can be referenced by a different user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to approach a scenario where an entity created by one user can be referenced by a different user?

You're capturing `CreatedBy`. So you can tell who is logged on, so you can enable editability on the web page for those things created by that user.

> Who should be able to view/edit/modify an EventArea entity?
>
> What happens if the EventArea is modified or deleted by the creating user?

This is entirely dependent on your system requirements. Only you can answer these questions.

It seems to me that if any user can *create* an EventArea then it is possible to create 2 or more EventAreas that are actually the same place down to the precision of your coordinate system and with exactly the same name.

**Do more Requirements Analysis**

> an EventArea represents a geographical location

If an "event area" can be any  10' x 10' spot in any public space anywhere in the country, then maybe users should be able to create them. But if we're talking about existing auditoriums, stadiums, campus, building, classroom, etc. then maybe they should be created by you and users can only select one.

And so maybe `an EventArea represents a place (classroom?), that has a geographical location`

**Do not allow user-editable keys**

If `Id` is a primary or foreign key into your database then `public ... set` is a bad idea. Never allow users to edit keys. Maybe they could create them as they created an object - I've had a case where this made sense - but *never* let an existing key be edited.

**Encapsulate Object Creation**

Use constructor parameters to control object creation, instead of publicly exposing all the properties. Otherwise you force client code to know everything about creating something. Required entry? Ranges? Valid property combinations? etc., etc.

In this case I'd expect to see something like this:

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    public string Description { get; protected set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; protected set; }
    public EventArea EventArea { get; protected set; }
    
    public Course (string name, string description, EventArea area) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Description = description;
        this.EventArea = area;
        this.Id = GenerateID();
        this.CreatedBy = FetchLoggedOnUser();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The entity code I put up was only to illustrate the entity relationships and not intended to be production ready... however the crux of my question is your point about it being possible to create 2 EventAreas which represent the same location. I am looking for a way to avoid this. An Event Area could be any Lat/Long globally so they are not something that can be created centrally.

Comment: We have some DB-level uniqueness constraints (in addition to the PKs and FKs) and we programmatically verify uniqueness of user entry. So you could do this on _name_ & _coordinate_ , in combination or not. In the UI maybe couple that to a `ComboBox` of existing EventAreas constrained geographically(?); and/or perhaps dynamically update the list as the user types. Our UI has a custom class - a textbox & popup fusion - the popup is practical for very long lists and is scrollable and filterable.

Comment: Good suggestions, thanks. Just discussing this issue with you has made me consider the problem differently. If I stick with the original implementation that each EventArea is unique only to each user I will instead focus my attention on how to query and display Courses/EventAreas on a map i.e. develop a service method to aggregate courses across event-areas which represent the same geographical location.